# How to relate the answers and questions in a dynamic form in php?

Tags: php, html, database

I want to create a dynamic form builder in php, similar to Google Forms and I have problems to relate answer and questions in the same form. I don't want to make a form for each question and relate the answer. I want one form with all questions and when I click save button the answers be saved with the respective question_id.

Should I create hidden inputs to send each question_id?

What would be the best way to do it?

DB design

[image]

Source code:

```
<form action="form.php">
<?php foreach ($questions as $question): ?>
    <div>
        <label><?= $question["title"] ?></label>
        <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="<?= $question["id"] ?>">

        <?php if ($question["type"] == "text"): ?>
            <input type="text" name="answer_text">
        </div>
        <?php elseif ($question["type"] == "select"): ?>
        <select name="areas">
            <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
                <option value="<?= $option["text"] ?>"><?= $option["text"] ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>

<button type="submit">Send</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add arrays to forms (and URL query arguments), by adding `[]` to the names of the parameters. This way you will receive in `form.php` a numeric array.

And you can also specify your keys:

```html
<form action="form.php">
    <?php
    foreach ($questions as $question):
        $qid = $question["id"];
    ?>
    <div>
        <label><?= $question["title"] ?></label>
        <input type="hidden"
            name="types[<?php echo htmlentities($qid) ?>]"
            value="<?= $question["type"] ?>" />

        <?php if ($question["type"] == "text"): ?>
            <input type="text"
                name="answer_text[<?php echo htmlentities($qid) ?>]" />
        <?php elseif ($question["type"] == "select"): ?>
            <select
                name="areas[<?php echo htmlentities($qid) ?>]">
                <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
                    <option value="<?= $option["text"] ?>"><?= $option["text"] ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </select>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

If you are 100% sure that the question ids will not contain any strange character, you can remove the `htmlentities()`s.